# Is it possible to blow up ferrengal using atomic detonators?

Tags: tradewars-2002

I've tried killing all the colonists, and then trying to blow up the planet... no luck.  Every time the colonists disarm the atomic detonator.

Comment: Wow, it's been a long time since I've had to answer a BBS game question.  What version of TW2002 are you playing?  Is it the new adaption or the classic BBS?

Comment: I'm playing v2.20b, It's pretty much the exact oldschool BBS game that works on telnet rather than doors.  I bought it here http://www.eisonline.com/products/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a config option in 'general editor two' called invincible ferrengal.

> This settings determines whether or not Ferrengal can be destroyed by
>   players.  The default is to allow Ferrengal to be destroyed like any
>   other planet.  By making it invincible, you can guarantee that the
>   planet will be around for the duration of the game.  This is important
>   for capture-the-flag or quest games that are centered around the
>   Ferrengi homeworld.
>
> NOTE:  This setting applies to standard Ferrengi, not Gold Ferrengi.
>
> Should Ferrengal be invincible? (Y/N) [N] :